# Update data from a sqlite file in other viewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm developing my first iOS application .
In this application , I am using Storyboard and it got some Views and TableViews use information captured from a SQLite file.

This file SQLite suffers updates constantly , so I created a PHP system that always updates and offers that SQLite file through a URL of my site .
In my application I've created a View configuration , which checks for a new SQLite file to download, and if you have , download this file and replace the existing database with the new. With that my application is always updated .

My problem is right there. When the user opens the application , it goes straight to a view that captures the information from the database and list in a table .
If, then, you go to the View configuration and update the database, that my first view will be updated only when the user restarting application.

Do not know if has to understand what is happening, but it seems like after reading the SQLite first, my application writes a kind of Cache. 
I need it as soon as you download and replace the database, I can force the application to update the information, even though the other Views have already been accessed or not.

Now appreciate the patience and help of all. 
hugs

Comment: It would take pages to describe a solution. Do some research on MVC (Model-View-Controller). You need your data in "model" objects. Your controllers need to be notified when the model is updated so the views can be updated.

Comment: Thank you for response.
Apparently, it is something more complex.
Is there a simpler way? Even though it is not so advised.
I've been giving some research before writing here, and I saw that if I put [self viewDidLoad] it does the 'reload' the View.

Really worked, but I can only update the View settings.
I would not like being in the View configuration, applying this viewDidLoad of the other screens?

Excuse my ignorance, as I said, I'm new to Xcode / Objective-C.
Thanks and hugs.

Comment: NEVER call `viewDidLoad` yourself. Bad, bad, bad.